# Examples of how SDK testing is done

Tags: manual-testing, quality-assurance, qa-role, qa-process

In my career as a QA focusing primarily on manual testing of web applications, I was only recently introduced to the concept of SDK testing.
I was hoping some people with experience in this area could give me some examples of how SDKs are tested? I understand that automation tools are available but what might some examples of manual SDK testing look like?

I did some research and all the results seem to be concerned with API testing. I understand that APIs can be an important feature of an SDK, but is that all there is to it? Is SDK testing, in practice, API testing? Or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIs are naturally part of SDKs. It is how you interface with code in libraries (jars, dlls, etc). When I worked on a library/package, I just had to write functional tests that used the library/package.

SDKs however are installable packages so there is also testing that goes along with that. When I worked on an installable toolbar we had to test the installation against many different Operating Systems. We also had to test it against many anti-virus vendors to address false-positives. There's also testing if the install is interrupted, or checking the background process for memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

FOr testing SDK the tool like fitnesse is a great and easy option ,

here fitnesse test are in data driven appraoach and triggers methods for each method in the sdk

http://docs.fitnesse.org/FrontPage